# virt-manager copy paste functionality to the vm

Tags: virtual-machine, vnc, clipboard, virt-manager

Anyone know how to get [Virtual Manager](http://virt-manager.org/) to install copy-paste functionality to the Virtual Machine?

Comment: Please describe more about "copy functionality". Which functionality do you need? Don't you access to ssh on the host?

Comment: adding to @shgnlnc: or you want bidirectional copy and paste for host and guest?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/858649/how-can-i-copypaste-from-the-host-to-a-kvm-guest

Answer (score 39):

You have to use "Spice" instead of "VNC" :

1. No more need to install `spice-gtk`: `virt-manager` has now a `spice-gtk` client built-in. But you need to install `python-spice-client-gtk` (`spice-client-gtk` on debian) **on the VM host**

   - If you use `virt-manager` on another machine to connect to the VM host remotely through ssh, you must also install `python-spice-client-gtk` on that machine
2. Start `virt-manager`
3. Select you virtual machine
4. Power on the virtual machine
5. Connect to your guest with `ssh` ; in the guest, install `spice-vdagent` and verify that `spice-vdagentd` is launched (`ps -lef|grep spice-vdagentd` will return you the process if its running)
6. Show virtual hardware details
7. Select `Display VNC`, change `VNC` to `Spice` and accept to add the Channel
8. Change the `Video model from Cirrus` (the default) to `QXL`
9. Restart `virt-manager` and power on the virtual machine

You are using Spice.

Another solution, without X, but assuming that you are able to `ssh` to your host from your machine, and to your VM from your host :

1. `mymachine:~$ssh user@host`
2. `host:~$ssh user@guest`

Comment: Should install these packages on a machine which virt-manager was installed on it? Or exactly on Host?

Comment: There is no more need to install spice-gtk. I have changed the answer.

Comment: Actually it seems that once you install `spice-vdagent` in guest, there's no need to restart `virt-manager` nor the guest to use clipboard sharing. It's enough to logout and then login back **in the guest.**

Comment: For me (on debian) only the daemon `spice-vdagentd` started after the reboot, without sharing the clipboard. I had to autostart `spice-vdagent` via _.xsessionrc_ to get it working.

Answer (score 27):

You need to install Spice guest agent into the guest:

- **[spice-guest-tools](https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-guest-tools/spice-guest-tools-latest.exe)** for Windows guest
- **spice-vdagent** for linux guest

Check "**Guest**" part of Spice downloads section:
https://www.spice-space.org/download.html

Comment: For Windows guest, in addition to installing spice-guest-tools, I needed to do the following in virt-manager: Add Hardware -> Channel, set name to "com.redhat.spice.0" (or similar), set device type as "Spice agent (spicevmc)". I found this info from this reddit post after searching for a long time: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/asw4wk/to_all_you_virtmanager_and_spice_display_users/

Comment: Update: The above channel name setting was not required for me. Just installing the spice-guest-tools for Windows 10 worked. Thanks

Comment: What about with a legacy guest os where tools are not available?  I'm trying to install ubuntu 10.04 as a guest.  I want to hijack the keyboard IO with my paste data.

Answer (score 6):

With a Linux (Debian 11/bullseye) host and a Windows 10 guest, I did the following to enable copy-and-paste between the guest and the host:

- Install `spice-guest-tools` on Windows guest; the binaries can be downloaded from https://www.spice-space.org/download.html.
- Install `spice-vdagent` on Linux host.
- Using `virt-manager` (on host) change the Windows VM configuration:

  - Set the 'Display' to  'Spice'.
  - Add a 'spicevmc' Channel (via 'Add Hardware');
    The XML data will be:

    > channel type="spicevmc"
    > target type="virtio"
    > name="com.redhat.spice.0"
    > alias name="channel0"
    > address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="2"
- In Linux host, enable `spice-vdagentd.service`; eg.

  ```
  # systemctl enable spice-vdagentd.service`
  ```
- Restart Linux.

The copy-and-paste functionality is ready to use.

Comment: Maybe you could add the filename where the XML data is applied?

Comment: I did it via `virt-manager`; the XML content is copied from the GUI. But if you want to change the VM configuration via editing the XML, then you could use the command `virsh edit <VM-name>`.

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS and "virt-manager/focal,focal,now 1:2.2.1", just "spice-guest-tools" is enough. Virt Manager switched to Spice server automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Barrier (software-based KVM) https://github.com/debauchee/barrier.

Install it on your host as the server. Install it on your VM as a client.

Here is what my client setup looks like.

[image: VM Barrier Configuration]

Next, tell Barrier where (spatially) your client is. This is personal preference, but I set mine to be above my host. It is kind of awkward since the VM obviously is nested inside your host, but it still works very well.

Click `Configure Server` on Barrier running on your host machine. Here is my setup:

[image: Host Barrier Configuration]

What you label the screen matters here. Notice, in my first image, the `Screen name` is "jareds-iMac". This has to match.

With this setup, when you move your mouse past the top of your screen, it switches into the VM. Copy-paste will work from host to machine and vice-versa. An added benefit is that you don't have to press any hotkeys to release the "grab" from the VM.

Answer (score 0):

On the latest Windows 11, both **Spice-Guest-Tools** and **Virtio-Win-Guest-Tools** need installing for clipboard sharing

---

Below is the same answer as above. But with details for those interested.

Steps:

1. On the Windows 11 Guest, install this latest **Spice-Guest-Tools** from https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-guest-tools/spice-guest-tools-latest.exe
2. On the Windows 11 Guest, install this latest **Virtio-Win-Guest-Tools** from https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/latest-virtio/virtio-win-guest-tools.exe
3. Reboot Windows 11 Guest
4. Done. Enjoy clipboard sharing.

No need to install anything on the Host. Except Virtual Manager (Virt-Manager). Also on the Host, no need to change any configuration with Virt-Manager. The default ones worked. In our case, Debian 12 Bookworm with GNOME Wayland.

---

Related ticket at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/spice/win32/spice-nsis/-/issues/19

Virtio documentation:

- https://github.com/virtio-win/virtio-win-pkg-scripts/blob/master/README.md
- https://github.com/virtio-win/virtio-win-guest-tools-installer/tree/163b5bbbbe0274ca9a0b18a1c49326d1e48caec3
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/4.4/html/virtual_machine_management_guide/installing_guest_agents_and_drivers_windows#Installing_the_Guest_Agents_and_Drivers_on_Windows